# Problem to uninstall AirDroid: Unfortunately, Settings has stopped

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung, uninstallation, system-error, airdroid

When I try to uninstall the app I got this message:

`Can't uninstall because this package is an active device administrator.`
In the same window I have a button: `MANAGE DEVICE ADMINISTRATORS`

When I follow this button I'm in `Device administration settings`. (normally you can reach it when you follow: `settings -> Lock screen and security -> Other security settings -> Device administration settings`) There are three items each of them have a switch on the side, which is turned on. When I try to unswich *AirDroid*, I got after some seconds the error message: `Unfortunately, Settings has stopped.` Also I'm not able to uncheck the other both items, but there is a different behavior.

I try to solve this error by cleaning the cash with no effect.

I like to remove the app because finally I don't need it and it consume a lot of battery even when I don't use it.

I have a Samsung XCover 3
with Android 6.0.1
and Kernel 3.10.9

Comment: Try disabling *Find Phone* permission before uninstall

Comment: @beeshyams thanks for the hint...where i find the `find phone` option? what is the normal purpose of it?

Comment: I wish I knew. Saw that here http://www.deleteaccounts.net/how-to-uninstall-airdroid-android-windowsmac/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The disabling Find Phone this has solved the problem! You must disable it within the AirDroid app.